# How can I stop music from playing multiple times when going back to the frame it starts from in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, soundchannel

I have a music track that starts on the first frame and plays throughout the entire application. When I go back to the first frame, the current music is still playing but the song starts again over the top of it. How can I make it so it only plays through once even after going back to that frame?

My code:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

mySound.load(new URLRequest("Stellardrone - Billions And Billions.mp3")); 
myChannel = mySound.play(); 
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.4);
```

Comment: SoundChannel are typically created by sound.play() so instantiating them is a waste of resource and memory, instead: var myChannel:SoundChannel; not: var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check to see if the sound (or sound channel) has been created yet or not:

```
var mySound:Sound;
var myChannel:SoundChannel;
if(!mySound){
    mySound = new Sound();
    mySound.load(new URLRequest("Stellardrone - Billions And Billions.mp3")); 
    myChannel = mySound.play(); 
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0.4); 
}
```